# Statistical significance for correlated significance tests

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, p-value

I refer to this article http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=the-mind-reading-salmon.

Is there a p-value equivalent for a set of significance tests, especially in the case where some of the tests are correlated? By correlated I mean that they are not completely independent, and considering them completely independent would underestimate the significance of a good test.

Comment: Many specific examples can be found at [tag:multiple-comparisons].

Comment: @RockScience So are you wanting an answer to the question: If the outcome of a set of significance tests are correlated, what is the probability of making one or more Type I errors if the null hypothesis is true for all tests?